# What is the cs_PostViews Table used for in Community Server

Tags: community-server

I'm running Community Server 2.1 at the moment.  My cs_PostViews table is at 200MB.  What is the exact use of this table.  Is it safe to truncate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself.

This table holds a list of every single unique URL that was requested and served.  I.e. no 404 type URLs and the number of times it has been requested.

I ended up truncating this table with no ill effects so far.